# Vertical spacing of \sin and \cos

Tags: formatting, delimiters

This is a random, silly question. I was writing two versions of my calc 1 final and came across something that is going to bug the crap out of me. I have noticed a different spacing format for one fraction verses another. Anyway, does anyone know why this spacing looks different?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{d}{dx}\big[\tan x\big] &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right]\\
    \frac{d}{dx}\big[\cot x\big] &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The top one formats the brackets perfectly, while the second looks off...
But yeah, it's just driving me nuts!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because you have `i` in `sin` and its height is different than that of `cos`. If you interchange `sin` and `cos`, every thing is normal. To avoid this, you may add `\vphantom{i}` in the numerator or, better, use `\biggl` and `\biggr` pair instead of `\left` and `\right`.  For more details on these `\big` family of delimiters,  please refer to `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsldoc` from command prompt), pages 15 and 16.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{d}{dx}\big[\tan x\big] &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right]\\
    \frac{d}{dx}\big[\cot x\big] &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right]
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{d}{dx}\big[\tan x\big] &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right]\\
    \frac{d}{dx}\big[\cot x\big] &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\cos x \vphantom{i}}{\sin x}\right]
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{d}{dx}\big[\tan x\big] &= \frac{d}{dx}\biggl[\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\biggr]\\
    \frac{d}{dx}\big[\cot x\big] &= \frac{d}{dx}\biggl[\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\biggr]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would also like to mention that using `\mathstrut` rather than `\vphantom{i}` is (possibly) an even more general solution, but it depends on personal taste what *exact* spacing is preferrable.

Comment: Please, teach the OP about the usage of `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead of `\big`

Answer (score 16):

This is a problem that shows up also in different situations. Consider

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\sin x}\sqrt{\cos x}
\]
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

which is horrible.

If we correct the definitions performed in `amsopn.sty` in the following way,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\protected\def\arccos{\qopname\relax o{\vphantom{i}arccos}}
\protected\def\cos{\qopname\relax o{\vphantom{i}cos}}

\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\sin x}\sqrt{\cos x}
\]
\end{document}
```

we get

[image]

I see no point in doing just local assignments, as the majority of operators have ascenders. Possibly also `\max` and the other few operators that don't have ascenders should be redefined in the same way.

In your case, we have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\protected\def\arccos{\qopname\relax o{\vphantom{i}arccos}}
\protected\def\cos{\qopname\relax o{\vphantom{i}cos}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\bigl[\tan x\bigr] &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right]\\
\frac{d}{dx}\bigl[\cot x\bigr] &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\bigl` and `\bigr` should be used, not the simple `\big`, so the delimiters are assigned the correct **Opening** and **Closing** type.

Comment: No doubt, you are a better teacher of TeX than me `:-)`